How to display Hue. Despite Style function is used, why are numeric values of Hues not displayed?
To be useable in code elsewhere, it would be useful to have colors displayed as their InputForm, but colored appropriately.
When I try
Style[Hue[0.], FontColor->Hue[0.]]

I just get the default formatting for Hue[0.]
Is there an easy way to get it to be styled like InputForm[Hue[0.]] but colored red?
Even better, is there a way to do this automatically?
Here's an illustration of the problem
Table[Style[Hue[h],Hue[h]],{h,0,1,0.1}]



You should display Hue[h], but just h! That is: Table[Style[h, Hue[h]], {h, 0, 1, 0.1}]. Hue[h] gets automatically converted to the corresponding color object, which is displayed as a little rectangle.

Table[Style[hue[h], Hue[h]], {h, 0, 1, 0.1}] notice the hue and Hue. Another possibility Table[Style["Hue[" <> ToString[h] <> "]", Hue[h]], {h, 0, 1, 0.1}].

Alternatively, you can also do: Table[Hue[Style[h, Hue[h]]], {h, 0, 1, 0.1}].

Hue[h] is a function.What about hue[h]?

I'm voting to reopen this, as even though the OP clearly doesn't understand the way the front-end operates, the actual question: "how can I make Hue[0.] display as StyleBox[RowBox[{"Hue", "[", "0.", "]"}, FontColor->Hue[0.]]] is an interesting one and deserves an answer on this site

@b3m2a1 It looks like the question will be re-opened. Let's edit the question to bring it up an acceptable level. I did some, can you continue?

While Mathematica works with expressions, we expect to also be able to have nice visualizations. That's the job of the front end. When you use Plot, that expression gets evaluated to a Graphics expression. Looking at that raw Graphics expression is usually not edifying. We want to see an actual plot. So, the front end knows how to display Graphics expressions as pretty pictures. Think of Hue and RGBColor and other color-related symbols as similar to Graphics. The front end has special rules for turning Hue expressions into pretty color indicators.
There are ways of looking at the raw expressions rather than the front end's pretty visualization. The most common is FullForm. If you try something like FullForm[Plot[x,{x,0,1]], you'll be able to see all of the gory details behind the pretty picture. Similarly if you do FullForm[Hue[0]], you'll see just the expression Hue[0] rather than the little color box. There are other *Form functions, including, InputForm, OutputForm, and TreeForm.
Beyond *Form functions, there are functions that suppress evaluation in different ways. For example Hold, HoldForm, Inactive/Inactivate, and Unevaluated. These functions can be used in some cases to interrupt the front end's normal display behavior.
So, applying this to your question, it seems like you want to show the "raw" color expression but styled to be the color that the color expression represents. My first attempt was this:
Table[Style[Inactivate[Hue[h]], Hue[h]], {h, 0, 1, .25}]


My thinking was that having Hue wrapped with Inactive will interfere with the front end display for Hue, but I didn't account for the fact that the front end has its own rules for displaying Inactive expressions. But maybe that result is sufficient for you.
Next I moved to trying *Form functions. The most satisfying was OutputForm:
Table[Style[OutputForm[Hue[h]], Hue[h]], {h, 0, 1, .25}]


Anyway, play around with the different *Form functions and the different evaluation manipulation functions until you get what you want.

You could supply custom definitions that apply to the TemplateBox that drives the styling of these expressions. You can see the template box provided by just calling TemplateBox[Hue[0.]] and see how it works. This could in principle be applied at the stylesheet level too

Two other comments in case I forget to submit an answer, 1) InputForm is probably a better choice than OutputForm here and 2) you can also do expr /. c:(h_[e___])?ColorQ :> Style[HoldForm[h][e], FontColor->c] or use Format rules

@b3m2a1 I think all of these comment are fine, but I'm not sure why you're putting them on my answer. Other than the suggestion to use InputForm rather than OutputForm, your suggestions are non-trivially different than mine. They deserve their own answer. Or is there something you want me to respond to?

Can't post an answer while the question is closed / can't be sure I'll remember to answer once it's open (I don't use mma.se much anymore)

@b3m2a1 FWIW, the reason I chose OutputForm is because in the original question, the step size of .1 resulted in many digits when using InputForm. Since the problem didn't really depend on the length of the list, I increased the step size to .25 just to reduce the size of the output, and at that step size it makes no difference, so my choice probably seemed weird.

@b3m2a1 Thanks for explaining. It would seem to me that your comments would be more appropriate on the original post where they are more likely to be seen. I don't mind and don't think it really matters--I'm just picking nits.
